# MVC5 CSS/Lay-Out working on one PC, not the other

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller

How it's supposed to look (and does look on one machine):

[image: How it's supposed to look (and does look on one machine)]

Then, when moved to another computer, this is the result. As if the layout and CSS is not rendered, but it seems to render when going through it with breakpoints:

[image: Then, when moved to another computer, this is the result. As if the layout and CSS is not rendered, but it seems to render when going through it with breakpoints]

Both PCs run Visual Studio 2017 with .NET Framework 4.5.2 and the files are identical on both. Any ideas where I should be looking to fix this, that'd be litty.

Comment: post the image directly. we are scared of external links

Comment: missing file(s)? different website/virtual direcory layout? missing static file routing in web.config? how did you deploy the solution: did you install a release build on the second one, or build from source and run from debugger on both? are the browsers, browser document modes, and browser compatibility mode settings the same?

Comment: It didn't allow me to post it directly, but it seems dlatikay has done so for me. Same exact files (literally copy-pasted to another computer), I've tried multiple browsers and they all give the same result. Only thing I've installed on the troublesome PC was ReSharper, but it worked with it before. I'm uninstalling it now to see if that changes anything, just to be sure.

Comment: Is it a responsive app? The bottom screenshot looks like it is catering to a narrower screen.

Comment: What about checking the chrome/web debugger?

Comment: Both screens have the same resolution, the application is responsive though. (If by responsive you mean that it sizes along with the window/screen size) | I've debugged it countless of times, everything seems fine to me. I've found an error when re-opening each CSS file separately, but it doesn't stop the application from running and it's in both files on both PCs, so I doubt it can be it. I'm having a third computer check to see if it's something related to this computer or the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

When this problem occurred for me it was a problem with IIS... On the second computer, open up Windows Features and ensure that the following option is checked:

[Windows Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qu5p.png)

Correction: It was a problem with allowing IIS to serve static content. 
I shouldn't bully IIS and needlessly blame it for things.

Comment: The whole service was turned off. I turned it on, but that didn't fix it either.